# Transferring guns and utilities to another ship?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Is it possible to transfer bought utilities and guns to another ship or are they fixed to the ship you buy it on?

I am still flying in a sidewinder and want to buy a kill warrant scanner since I mostly do bounty hunting. I have found this place where i can buy rating F to C but I do not want to waste much money since I can get a viper pretty soon.

So can I put these utilities in a Hangar for later use or even transfer them to other places?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **UPDATE:** This all changed in a release a few months ago.

In outfitting, there's an option to 'transfer' or 'store' any module. When you buy another module for a slot, there's an option to store the one you have equipped or to sell it. Simply store a module, switch ships, and transfer the module from module storage. If you try to store a required module (powerplant, fsd, etc), it will put an 'E' rated version on (which you'll have to pay the cost of).

Additionally, you can move these modules without having to fly them in a ship. It costs credits and takes time, both of which increase the further away it is.

### Old outdated info that is now wrong:

**Yes**, it's possible to move them from one ship to another, however, you **can't store them**.

If you're in a station with outfitting and a shipyard (with the ship you want to buy), you can sell the utilities and guns on your current ship in outfitting, switch ships in the shipyard, then go back into outfitting and you'll have an option to "rebuy" the stuff you just sold at the same price you just sold it at. If you undock and come back, that rebuy option will be gone. I'm not sure they'll still be there if you quit and restart, either.

Make sure you have enough money to buy the new ship and to buy back your parts.

Comment: Ok, strange mechanics. They should have chosen for the same kind of structure as in eve online. Everything there is transportable as long as the ship is large enough, eventually every thing is "just" a item there.

Comment: I've actually bought sidewinders just to take advantage of this mechanism and store equipment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2.2 Guardians, it is possible to store modules in stations where the Outfitting service is available. You can even have them transferred them between systems (for a fee).

[Elite Guardians release notes](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/300177-Elite-Dangerous-The-Guardians-2-2-update):

> - Module storage added to Outfitting
> - Stored modules can be sold
> - Module transfers with delivery times added

The functionality is available even without Horizons season pass.